# Too many scsi hosts in /sys/class/scsi_host. Only one SCSI controller is used, other two are not used

Tags: linux

I have 8 disks in my virtual bastion server whose PCI address is also shared here along with the host ID which controls them. However `lspci` lists three drive controllers. Does it mean that the other two are not used at all and only `SCSI Controller: LSI Logic` is used here. Why `host0 and other hosts` are there if only `host2` is used.

```
[root@linux_server ~]# fdisk -l | grep -i disk |grep -v identifer | grep -v identifier | grep -v mapper

Disk /dev/sda: 46.2 GB, 46170898432 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
Disk /dev/sdd: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
Disk /dev/sde: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
Disk /dev/sdc: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
Disk /dev/sdf: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
Disk /dev/sdg: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes
Disk /dev/sdh: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes
```

```
[root@linux_server ~]# ls -l /sys/block/sd*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:39 /sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:39 /sys/block/sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:1/2:0:1:0/block/sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:39 /sys/block/sdc -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:2/2:0:2:0/block/sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:39 /sys/block/sdd -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:3/2:0:3:0/block/sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:39 /sys/block/sde -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:4/2:0:4:0/block/sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:39 /sys/block/sdf -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:5/2:0:5:0/block/sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:39 /sys/block/sdg -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:6/2:0:6:0/block/sdg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:39 /sys/block/sdh -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:8/2:0:8:0/block/sdh
```

```
[root@linux_server ~]# lspci | egrep -i "sata|scsi|ide"

00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:10.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev 01)
02:04.0 SATA controller: VMware SATA AHCI controller
```

```
[root@linux_server ~]# cat /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/proc_name | wc -l

33
```

```
[root@linux_server ~]# ls -l /sys/class/scsi_host/host*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:24 /sys/class/scsi_host/host0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/host0/scsi_host/host0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:24 /sys/class/scsi_host/host1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/host1/scsi_host/host1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host10 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host10/scsi_host/host10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host11 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host11/scsi_host/host11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host12 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host12/scsi_host/host12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host13 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host13/scsi_host/host13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host14 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host14/scsi_host/host14
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host15 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host15/scsi_host/host15
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host16 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host16/scsi_host/host16
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host17 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host17/scsi_host/host17
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host18 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host18/scsi_host/host18
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host19 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host19/scsi_host/host19
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:24 /sys/class/scsi_host/host2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/scsi_host/host2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host20 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host20/scsi_host/host20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host21 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host21/scsi_host/host21
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host22 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host22/scsi_host/host22
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host23 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host23/scsi_host/host23
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host24 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host24/scsi_host/host24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host25 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host25/scsi_host/host25
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host26 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host26/scsi_host/host26
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host27 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host27/scsi_host/host27
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host28 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host28/scsi_host/host28
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host29 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host29/scsi_host/host29
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:24 /sys/class/scsi_host/host3 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host3/scsi_host/host3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host30 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host30/scsi_host/host30
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host31 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host31/scsi_host/host31
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host32 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host32/scsi_host/host32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:24 /sys/class/scsi_host/host4 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host4/scsi_host/host4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:24 /sys/class/scsi_host/host5 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host5/scsi_host/host5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host6 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host6/scsi_host/host6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host7 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host7/scsi_host/host7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host8 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host8/scsi_host/host8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 06:27 /sys/class/scsi_host/host9 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:04.0/host9/scsi_host/host9
```

```
[root@linux_server ~]# for i in `ls /sys/class/scsi_host/`; do echo $i; cat /sys/class/scsi_host/$i/proc_name| grep -i mpt; done

host0
host1
host10
host11
host12
host13
host14
host15
host16
host17
host18
host19
host2
mptspi
host20
host21
host22
host23
host24
host25
host26
host27
host28
host29
host3
host30
host31
host32
host4
host5
host6
host7
host8
host9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`host0` and `host1` are from this one:

```
00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
```

It supports the VMware virtual CD/DVD emulation. The physical version of that controller had two IDE channels, and if I recall correctly, VMware allows using up to two virtual CDs simultaneously.

Your actual `/dev/sd*` disk devices seem to be currently via `host2`, which is this one:

```
 00:10.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev 01)
```

That's VMware emulating a simple parallel SCSI controller, for maximum compatibility.

`host3` ... `host32` are related to `VMware SATA AHCI controller`, which seems to have no actual disks presented through it.

Aside from consuming some memory, that should not be harmful; but you might ask the VMware host administrator to check the configuration of your VM, and to remove the currently-unused virtual SATA AHCI controller from the virtual hardware configuration unless it's not needed.

Perhaps the host administrator has attempted to upgrade the controller type at a previous maintenance break, but had to roll back the change because your VM was not configured to support VMware PVSCSI or any other more modern disk controller types.

[For maximum performance, PVSCSI seems to be the best option](https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2014/02/vscsi-controller-choose-performance.html) as it eliminates duplication of work between the VM and the host.

Comment: Thanks @telcoM for the response. I just checked the hardware configuration of the VM. It does have a SATA Controller 0 (AHCI) as well as 1 IDE controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with vmware where I had not attached any SCSI devices at all and yet linux showed incredible amount of them to something like `/dev/sdg`. My disk was IDE so I figured out to edit `machine.vmx` and change from `scsi0.present = "TRUE"` to `"FALSE"`. That resolved my issue.